# NSXMLParserDelegate objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I parse `<param name="Weight">630.00 гр</param>` to get `630`? When I use the following I get `elementName = param`, but `attributeDict` contains only the dictionary - `"name":"Weight"`.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is using the function below.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  //the parser found some characters in-between an opening and closing tag
  //what are you going to do?
}
```

You need to store the state, when the `attributeDict` contains the `"name":"Weight"` tag. Than the parser will call the above function, and you should be able to read `630` from there.